Configuring inter-VLAN routing and dynamic IP addressing via DHCP, on each of my VLANs in GNS3 witch PFSENSE

Good evening everyone, I am in the process of carrying out a computer network project based on the configuration and routing of VLAN networks. Here is my network topology and I have already done the configuration on distribution devices, but my problem is that my virtual machines connected to each of the VLANs that correspond to it do not receive the dynamic IP address that I have in the DHCP addressing range?

Please edit your questions to include the configurations, We cannot guess at it.
